# Microphone not working in Mac Mini after system update

Tags: mac, macos, audio

I have a Mac Mini Mid 2011 Model. Earlier when I used OX X 10.7.5 my microphone was working fine.  I updated my system to Yosemite 10.10.2 and my microphone stopped working. In System Preferences-->Sound-->Input, I am getting Line In (Name) Audio Line-In port(TYPE).

I am using Iball headphones.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to different areas of Stack Exchange. Pick one & stick to it.

Comment: @Tetsujin someone at other site told that you should try apple.stackexchange

Comment: Someone [me] posted a link to an answer on Ask Different; I didn't see any specific request for it to be migrated, which would have been the better option.

Comment: i am having problem in microphone and not heaphones/speakers

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the following files...

From the root folder -

**/Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.DeviceSettings.plist**

**/Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.SystemSettings.plist**

From your Home folder -

**/Library/Preferences/com.apple.audio.AudioMIDISetup.plist**

It may be worth installing the current build of [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html) and clearing out the **System** and **User caches** before restarting your Mac. Hopefully your audio devices will be set back to their defaults and your mic will work again.